# Is it possible to find the sum $ \sum {e^{j\cos(n\theta)}}$?

Tags: trigonometry, summation, trigonometric-series

I am trying to have a closed form for the summation below and I am not sure whether it is possible or not.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{j A \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{N}n-B\right)} $$
Where A and B are constants.

Comment: Seems unlikely.

Comment: couldn't be there even any approximation?